# Web service gets empty array from SOAP request instead of array with strings

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, web-services, soap

I have a situation where I send SOAP request with array of strings via Ajax and the request is passed successfully to the web service however the desearialized array is empty.

I have ASP.Net WebService with the following contract:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://someCompany.com/WebServices/TCWS/Agent")]
public class AgentService : WebService
```

With the following API:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "my action description", MessageName = "MyAction")]
public Result MyAction(string[] items)
```

I do a request via AJAX (Javascript) with the following code:

```
AgentService.prototype.DoSoapAjax = function (methodName, data, successHandler, errorHandler, state) {
    // Need to use local variable so ajax request will be able to process the guid variable
    var currGuid = window.AgentGUID;

    var response = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        methodName: methodName,
        url: this.AgentServiceUrl,
        data: data,
        async: this.Async,
        beforeSend: function (req, methodName) {
            var soapActionURI = "http://someCompany.com/WebServices/TCWS/Agent/" + this.methodName;
            req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", soapActionURI);
            req.setRequestHeader("AgentGUID", currGuid);
        },
        success: function (xml, textStatus) {
            if (successHandler != null) {
                var response = xml.lastChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild;
                successHandler(state, $.xml2json(response), textStatus);
            }
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { if (errorHandler != null) errorHandler(state, xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown); }
    });

    if (!this.Async) {
        var syncResponse = new Object();
        syncResponse.response = response;
        syncResponse.json = $.xml2json(response.responseText);
        return syncResponse;
    }

    return response;
};
```

This is how I cal DoSoapAjax:

```
AgentService.prototype.MyAction= function (items, successHandler, errorHandler, state) {
    var items = "<items arrayType='string[]'><item xsi:type='string'>first text</items><item xsi:type='string'>second text</items></items>"

    var methodName = "MyAction ";
    var soapXml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body>"
    soapXml += "<" + methodName + " xmlns='http://someCompany.com/WebServices/TCWS/Agent'>";
    soapXml += items;
    soapXml += "</" + methodName + "></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

    var response = this.DoSoapAjax("MyAction", soapXml, successHandler, errorHandler, state);
    return response;
};
```

And the SOAP request is the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
        <soap:Body>
            <MyAction xmlns='http://someCompany.com/WebServices/TCWS/Agent'>
                <items xsi:type='string'>first text</items>
                <items xsi:type='string'>second text</items>
            </MyAction>
        </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When I debug the web service I can see that I get to MyAction method however items is an empty array instead of array with 2 strings...

Is there something wrong with my SOAP request ?

Comment: It looks to me like you are passing multiple string parameters instead of an array of strings

Comment: How are you calling `DoSoapAjax`? Can you post that code?

Comment: @lc. Added the caller function of DoSoapAjax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some solution however I don't understand why it works since I can't find any documentation on it.
I've changed my SOAP request to the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
        <soap:Body>
            <MyAction xmlns='http://someCompany.com/WebServices/TCWS/Agent'>
                <items>
                    <string>first text</string>
                    <string>second text</string>
                </items>
            </MyAction>
        </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Can someone please post an explanation or documentation regarding that so it will be more clear? It looks like when I pass an **element** I put its **name** and when it is **array** I put its **type**. I've found that solution in some small google doc...
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

The data object is not being passed as an array of strings, but is being added to the body as individual string parameters. The correct SOAP should look something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
        <soap:Body>
            <MyAction xmlns='http://CosmoCom.com/WebServices/TCWS/Agent'>
                <items arrayType="string[]">
                    <item xsi:type='string'>first text</items>
                    <item xsi:type='string'>second text</items>
                </items>
            </MyAction>
        </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I think to make data into an array you can use

```
var itemArray = jQuery.makeArray(data);
```

Comment: Thanks. However tried it and it still does not work. I get Bad Request 400

Comment: What does the SOAP request look like now?

Comment: the SOAP request looks exactly like the one you stated above

Comment: I think I found a solution but I don't really understand why it works since I haven't found similar documentation for it. maybe you are familiar with that. I'll post my answer soon